# Could not found POS-80 C driver required for macOS

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, printing, driver

I am using a billing printer from a local vendor [black copper company](http://www.blackcopper.net/) and i am using this [link](https://www.xprintertech.com/drivers-2#:%7E:text=Receipt%20Printer%20(Mac)) to download the driver POS-80 and my printer is running successfully but my main problem is, I cant find any driver with cutter properties,
In windows it is easily available but in mac it is available but without cutter.

**Any suggestion for pos-80 c driver or there is any settings issue i am missing**

Comment: Have you tried querying the manufacturer?

Comment: Yes but they have drivers for Windows, linux, ios, and android, but not macos